# Custom JSON Response from Scrapy Spider Deployed via Scrapyd

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

I need to find a way to make my Scrapy spider return a custom JSON response. It is deployed via scrapyd using `schedule.json`. Schedule.json responds with `JobID` and `Status`, but I'd like to add some more data to that response.

If there's a way I could do it by creating a separate response and then make a separate request that would work as well.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

<sup>(taken from [Learn to Read the Source, Luke](http://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/)).</sup>

It is doable.

Implement your own `resource` based on [`scrapyd.webservice.WsResource`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/b7699de462587efe27a7d64d491750a5904a5ce0/scrapyd/webservice.py#L10-L24), write a `render_POST()` method. Then, tell `scrapyd` to use your `schedule.json` resource implementation:

```
[services]
schedule.json = project.module.MySchedule
```

Comment: Sorry for the image, just love to quote it :)

Comment: Thanks! What docs? I've read through the Scrapyd documentation and didn't come across that...